# Sahadeva knew future events in Mahabharata. How many times did he use this knowledge in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas

I am not sure about it. I have just read folk story about this.

[Is Pandu's last wish, not to burn his body but eat it away, real?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3518/14980)

Is there any valid scripture available for this story?

If yes,

Then, How many times did he use this knowledge in Mahabharata?

Comment: Board Can You have any Reference about your question.

Comment: I have read this answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5455/14980

Comment: It Is Folk Story no Real Reference.

Comment: I didn't have other reference. Please provide if you have a proper reference.

Answer (score 4):

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahadeva#Special_Skills), although Sahadev was aware of possible future events,  he was cursed that if he disclosed the events to anyone then his head would split into pieces.

Since he did not died by his head splitting into 2, is perhaps a good indication that he did not used his "future" seeing power during the war.

However, [before the start of the War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahadeva#Role_in_the_Kurukshetra_War), because Sahadeva was very good in Astrology, Duryodhana, on the advice of Shakuni approached Sahadeva in order to seek the right time to start the Mahabharata war so that the Kauravas will be victorious.

Sahadeva disclosed the same for the Kauravas in spite of knowing that Kauravas were their enemy,

Comment: I appreciate your answer but still, I don't clear my doubt, that what Sahadeva disclosed about the war to Duryodhana?

Comment: @YogeshBorad i answered your original Question in post, which was about whether Sahadev used his power or not. Now, what Sahadeva disclosed about the war to Duryodhana is  another Question all together and you can raise that as new Question.