# Does krishna meet ramachandra?

Tags: krishna, death

Does krishna see rama meditating in the forest before his death? is that weird?  how can two so-called avatar be on earth together?   is this confusion with balarama?

ALSO, who is depicted in the art?  balarama or rama?
[image]

Comment: I think it's Lord Bala-Rāma. Who is also called as Rāma but because of his strength Bala is added to his name. Also, the picture is showing Lord Sesa is departing from him, plus his colour is not blue in the painting. As for 2 avatāras Lord Rāma and Lord Parshu Rāma met. Lord Parshu Rāma was also there during Lord Krishna and he is also here now as a Cheeranjivi. As for avesha or purna avatār well Lord Krishna (and Arjuna) met Lord Vishnu in Krishna Bhagwat Puran and also in Mahābhārata while praying to Lord Shiva. Lord Rāma also met Lord Vishnu in Sri Shiva Gita part of Padma Puran. ..

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/is-there-any-story-behind-lord-krishnas-death accepted answer says he meets both rama and balarama in meditation before he dies

Comment: I like comments... verses are mandatory?! I did not remember that...wasn’t sure

Comment: Authentic verses are mandatory to back your point up with proofs otherwise any one can say anything. Bdw, i see u have edited ur comment which earlier said that "i can make my own verses". Well you can. Even you can write a whole book. But here it will not work as you have to give verses from authentic scriptures not from some fiction. As for why i think its pretty obvious. Rest you can ask the mods, they will help you. N that's good you like comment enjoy it. Anyways, chalo babye. Cya. Tc..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any story behind Lord Krishna's death?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/is-there-any-story-behind-lord-krishnas-death)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Rāma Lord Krishna saw during the time of his death was the Rāms of the Yādava clan aka Bala Rāma his elder brother.**

**The Mahabharata. Book 16: Mausala Parva. Section 4.:**

> *Proceeding then to the forest, Keshava beheld **Rama** sitting in a solitary spot thereof. **He also saw that Rama** had set himself to Yoga and that **from out his mouth was issuing a mighty snake.** The colour of that snake was white. Leaving the human body (in which he had dwelt so long), that high-souled naga of a 1,000 heads and having a form as large as that of a mountain, endued besides with red eyes, proceeded along that way which led to the ocean.*

The OP's confusion of Lord Krishna seeing 2 Rāmas might occur due to the sentence *"He also saw Rāma"*. But that "also" was in the context with Lord Krishna seeing Lord Sesa leaving his human body viz Lord Bal Rāma while he was in meditation. It's not that he saw another Rāma. As the very next para clears all the confusion .

> ***After his brother had thus departed from the (human) world,** Vasudeva of celestial vision, who was fully acquainted with the end of all things, wandered for some time in that lonely forest thoughtfully...*

**Plus, Its also not weird if any avtār of Lord Vishnu meets another one or any avātar meets Lord Vishnu himself.**

**Lord Parshurama meets Lord Rama.**

**Valmiki Ramayana Sarga 74.:**

> *In that catastrophic darkness, that sand-muffled military of **king Dasharatha has seen the son of Sage Jamadagni, namely Bhaargava Rama,** the subjugator of kings of kings. He appeared calamitous in his look by wearing tufty matted and unruly head-hair, an unassailable one like Mt. Kailash, an unbearable one like the Epoch-End-Fire, irradiant with his own radiance, hence imperceivable for commoners, and such as he is, he clinched an axe on his right shoulder and clasped a bow in his left hand, that in simile is like a congeries of electroluminescence, and handling an arrow which is as if ready to electrocute, and he vied in his overall look with the devastator of triple cities, namely God Shiva. **[1-74-16b, 17, 18, 19].***
>
> .
>
> *On receiving the deference paid by the sage Vashishta, **that inexorable Rama of Jamadagni started to talk to Rama of Dasharatha.** **[1-74-24].***

**Lord Rama seeing Lord Vishnu.**

**The Fourth Chapter of Shiva Gita present in Uttara Khanda of Padma Purana.:**

> *Thereafter Rama saw dikpalakas seated on their respective divine vehicles with their respective consorts and singing hymns of Sama Veda. **Then Sri Rama sighted in front of Paramashiva, the lord Vishnu who held discus, conch, mace, and sword in his hands, who was shining brillinantly with a dark bluish hue, who was seated on his vehicle named Garuda, the Eagle, with goddess Sridevi who resembled like a streak of lightening and who was singing Rudradhyayana (Sri Rudram hymn).** **[36, 37, 38].***

**Lord Krishna seeing Lord Vishnu.**

**In Mahabharata , Anushasana Parva, ie., In Book 13, Chapter 15 verses 1 to 51.**

> "***The blessed Krishna continued** ... I stood all the while, supporting myself upon one foot and with my arms also raised upwards, and foregoing sleep all the while I then beheld, O Bharata, in the firmament an effulgence that seemed to be as dazzling as that of a thousand Suns combined together. . . . The puissant Indra, **Bhagawan Vishnu**, the sons of Aditi, and the Grandsire Brahma, all uttered, in the presence of Bhava, the Rathantara Saman.*

**Lord Krishna and Arjuna meeting Lord Vishnu.**

**ŚB 10.89.57.:**

> ***Lord Kṛṣṇa offered homage to the self (atmān) of all, the boundless (anantām) one, and Arjuna, astonished at the sight of Lord Mahā-Viṣṇu, bowed down as well.** Then, as the two of them stood before Him with joined palms, the almighty Mahā-Viṣṇu, supreme master of all rulers of the universe, smiled and spoke to them in a voice full of solemn authority.*

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142513/discussion-on-answer-by-savdy-does-krishna-meet-ramachandra); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.