# Is Parshuram poorna-avatar of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, avatars

Parshuram is avatar of Vishnu .  Is he poorna-avatar of Vishnu ?
What is the difference between poorna avatar and ansh-avatar of Vishnu ?

Poorna avatar = Full incarnation
Ansh avatar = Part incarnation.

Answer (score 4):

parashurAma is not poorna avatAra (**six qualities**) as per [padmapurANa uttarakhanDa ch. 229](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365813.html) :

> ***ṣāḍguṇyaparipūrṇo**'sau vāsudevaḥ sanātanaḥ | triguṇādātmanorūpaṃ caturddhā kurute jagat || 33 ||*
>
> *That ancient Vāsudeva is **full of six qualities**. From himself having the qualities (of sattva, rajas and tamas) he made his form,
> the world, into four.*
>
> *ityaṃtaryyāmyavasthāyāmaṃtaryyāmitvamātmanaḥ | matsyaḥ kūrmmo varāhaśca narasiṃho'tha vāmanaḥ || 40 ||*
> *rāmo rāmaśca kṛṣṇaśca buddhaḥ kalkī ca te daśa | ete tu vibhavāvasthā brahmaṇaḥ paramātmanaḥ || 41 ||*
>
> *Thus the state of the inner-controllership of self consists in his being the innermost soul.*
> *Matsya, Kūrma, Varāha, Narasiṃha, Vāmana, Rāma, Paraśurāma, Kṛṣṇa, Buddha and Kalki are the ten Vibhavas (incarnations) of Brahman, the
> highest soul.*
>
> ***nṛsiṃharāmakṛṣṇeṣu ṣāḍguṇyaṃ parikīrtitam** | parāvasthā tu devasya dīpādutpanna dīpavat || 42 ||*
>
> *The group of **six qualities** is said to exist in **Nṛsiṃha, Rāma and Kṛṣṇa**.*

Answer (score -2):

No, Lord Parshurama is a part avatar.

**Lord Parshurama meets Lord Rama.:**

**Valmiki Ramayana.:**

> *On receiving the deference paid by the sage Vashishta, **that inexorable Rama (the son) of Jamadagni started to talk to Rama (the son) of Dasharatha.** [1-74-24].*

As, I have discussed in [this answer of mine](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53947/20968) even Lord Krishna and Lord Rama are also part avatar.

**Srimad Devi Bhagwatam Mahā Puranam 5:1:12-54. says thus.:**

> *12-54. Vyāsa said :-- “..... **Again the Ṛṣi Nārāyaṇa is the part incarnate of Viṣṇu, and Vāsudeva is the part incarnate of the Ṛṣi Nārāyaṇa; hence what wonder is there, if Vāsudeva be seen to adore and propitiate Śiva? Śiva is the God of gods; and He is the Lord of all the causal bodies that exist; in the state of Suṣupti (deep sleep). In this respect, Śiva is the creator of Viṣṇu and Viṣṇu worships Him in this light. Rāma, Kṛṣṇa and others are all part incarnations of Viṣṇu; so there is no wonder if they worship Śiva**......."*

I hope this clarifies your queries. Prd..