# Age difference between Bhishma & Abhimanyu

Tags: mahabharata, bhishma, abhimanyu

Bhishma had the boon "Ichchha-Mrutyu" (one who can decide when to die). So he saw four generations of his family. I just want to know, what was the age difference between Bhishma & Abhimanyu in the Mahabharata?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5172/36) the age of various Mahabharata characters.  In particular, Bhishma was 140 years old at the time of the Mahabharata war.  Now as you can see in [this web page](http://www.hindunet.org/hindu_history/ancient/mahabharat/mahab_patnaik.html), Abhimanyu was born 12 years after Yudhishthira's coronation in Indraprastha, and Yudhishthira was coronated at the age of 46.  So since (as I discuss in that answer) Yudhishthira was 91 years old at the time of the Mahabharata war, Abhimanyu was 33 years old at the time of the war (contrary to the popular belief that he was 16).  **So Bhishma was 107 years older than Abhimanyu.**

Comment: you are incoreect about age of yudhishthira and abhimanyu. abhimanyu was 14 years old at the time of war

Comment: and if yudishthara was 91 years old at war time, his diff of age with bhishma is only 49 years. which is not possible.

Comment: @VikasRana Where did you hear that Abhimanyu was 14?  Abhimanyu was born long before the Pandavas 12-year exile.  As far as Bhishma goes, the reason that the age difference between Bhishma and Yudhishthira is only 49 years is that Vichitravirya and Chitrangada died at an early age, and Dhritarashtra and Pandu were born shortly after Vichitravirya's death.  And then Dhritarashtra and Pandu got married at an early age.

Comment: hmm ok. but how can a person saw his fourth generation when he was only 49 (bhima was not young when vichitervirya and chitrangad born). is there any written evidence for it.

Comment: @VikasRana Bhishma was just a boy when Ganga gave him back to Shantanu, and this chapter of the Adi Parva of the Mahabharata describes how Shantanu married Satyavati four years later: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01101.htm So Bhishma would have been about 16 when Vichitravirya and Chitrangada were born, which would make him in his early 30's when Pandu and Dhritarashtra were born, and then he was 49 when Yudhishthira was born.

Comment: @VikasRana You're welcome.  By the way, you may be interested in my question here about ages of characters in the Ramayana: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6527/36

Comment: I think that as per a boon given to chandra-dev (moon god) Abhimanyu was supposed to die before he reaches the age of 14, as 14 is suppose to be a juvenile age in Hinduism.

Comment: @V.Aggarwal I think the age 14 thing is just folklore.  Here is all Chandra says in the Adi Parva of the Mahabharata: “I cannot give (part with) my son. He is dearer to me than life itself. Let this be the compact and let it be not transgressed. The destruction of the Asuras on earth is the work of the celestials, and, therefore, it is our work as well. Let this Varchas, therefore, go thither, but let him not stay there long.” http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I remember reading this about being 14, I don't believe in folklore either, I read it. I will try to find the reference in my copy, though I might be wrong as it has been a few years since I read it.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think I found it (Unintentionally though), http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm "And let him, ye best of immortals, stay on earth for sixteen years." "And when he attaineth to his sixteenth year, the battle shall take place...". So Abhimanyu was 16 when he died.

Answer (score 0):

Difference should be **~70+/- years**.

As discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16040/1049), Drona died at the age of 85 years. From that, we can assume that Bhishma's age should be of **85-90 years**, as both Bhishma & Drona were contemporaries along with KripachArya.

Abhimanyu's age was **16 years** as mentioned in [Sambhava Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm):

> Nara, whose companion is Narayana, will be born as Indra's son and indeed, will be known as **Arjuna**, the mighty son of Pandu. This boy of mine shall be **his son** and become a mighty car-warrior in his boyhood. And let him, ye best of immortals, stay on earth for **sixteen years**. And when he attaineth to his sixteenth year, the battle shall take place in which all who are born of your portions shall achieve the destruction of mighty warriors...