# After Ashwatthama's massacre, why didn't any of the Pandavs marry another woman, and obtain another child?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas, ashwatthama

After the Kurukshetra War, Ashwatthaman directs the Brahmastra into the wombs of the Pandava women. My question is: Why didn't one of the Pandavas simply marry and get another child? Was there any particular reason there were unable to do so?

Comment: I don't think they were unable to, they just chose not to.  They already had an heir to the throne, namely Abhimanyu's father Parikshit, so they had no reason to have more children.  And often someone who has lost a child has no desire to have more children.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Cannot VTC this one as duplicate of [Why did Lord Krishna give another life to Parixit? Was it the only way? Why didn't Pandavas plan another child?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10150/2995)

Comment: @sv. OK, I closed it.