# How old was Drona?

Tags: mahabharata, dronacharya

This is something I had asked, since I know, the Pandavas were at least 90 years old or even older, but a friend told me that Drona was 80 years old. Something contradictory, since Arjuna was 100 years old or close to 100, along with Drona becoming the guru of the Pandavas and Kauravas in his childhood.

So my question is, how old was Drona?

Comment: From the above duplicate, see [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16040/1049). Drona was 85 years, which is explicitly mentioned in the scripture. The other being, Abhimanyu who was 16. From that you can infer PAndava-s & shri Krishna were in their late 30s or early 40s.

Comment: Abhimanyu was not 33 years old, he was born shortly before the forest fire Khandava, and Dhritarashtra mentions that 33 years passed after that just like Arjuna was almost a grandfather. So they had to be older than 30-40 years

Comment: This question is specific to Drona. So needs to be answered separately. Users don't have to search for answers under other umbrella questions. The other question doesn't even mention Drona.

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/30217/12304