# What is the correct translation of the Mahabharata verse mentioning Drona's age?

Tags: mahabharata, translation-request, dronacharya

There is a verse in [Mahabharata: Drona Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs07165.htm):

> **Sanskrit verse in Devnagri:**
>
> आकर्णपलितः शयामॊ वयसाशीति पञ्चकः
>
> तवत्कृते वयचरत संख्ये स तु षॊडद वर्षवत
>
> **Sanskrit verse in IAST Transliteration:**
>
> ākarṇapalitaḥ śyāmo vayasāśīti pañcakaḥ
>
> tvatkṛte vyacarat saṃkhye sa tu ṣoḍada varṣavat

As mentioned in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16040/12304), K. M. Ganguli translates it as below:

> Of a dark complexion, with white locks hanging down to his ears, **that old man of five and eighty years of age**, used, for thy sake only, to career on the field of battle with the activity of a youth of sixteen.

But Sanskrit-Hindi version by Gitapress translates it as below:

> [image: Drona age 400 years]

That means one translation says the age of Drona was 85  years (80+5) while another says the age of Drona was 400 years (80*5).

Can anyone please clarify how others translated this or provide meaning after breaking words and then using Sanskrit number system?

Comment: Vayasa asiti panchaka - i think this part is telling abt the age then how did they come up with 400 yrs? 85 yrs is the correct one.

Comment: Oh now I got it; they have taken Asitipanchaka to mean 80*5=400

Answer (score 2):

Acc to [Bibek debroy](https://archive.org/details/the-mahabharata-set-of-10-volumes-by-bibek-debroy-veda-vyasa-vyasa-veda-vyas-z-lib.org/page/n4161/mode/2up?view=theater)

> His grey hair hung down, up to his ears. He was dark. He was eighty-five years in age. But he had roamed around on the field of battle like one who was sixteen years old.

Acc to [MN Dutt](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharataMNDutt/page/n1791/mode/2up?q=drona%20parva&view=theater)

> Dhristadyumna began to send up loud war-cries whirling his sword all the while in the air. With his hoary locks flowing down his ears, of a dark complexion that old man of eighty-five years,

Also 85 years makes sense and not 400 [see this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/how-could-octogenarian-heroes-fight-in-mahabharata/16039#16039).

Comment: "Also 85 years makes sense and not 400 How could octogenarian heroes fight in Mahabharata?" -- did u see this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5177/12304 ?

Comment: @YDS yes I saw , but again vedas can be trusted blindly , so I guess vedas are right