# At what age did Arjuna recieve the knowledge of Srimad BhagavadGita from Sri Krishna?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

At what age did Arjuna recieve the knowledge of Srimad BhagavadGita from Sri Krishna? Do our holy scriptures mention anything regarding this?

Thnks a lot.

Comment: Answer is already present Pls.see-https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5172