# How many years did Lord Vishnu's human incarnations live for?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, rama, avatars, kalki

As per [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17621/lord-shree-rama-ruled-his-kingdom-for-11000-years) lord Ram must live more then 10000 years as if he ruled his kingdom for 10000 yrs. So **How many years did lord Rama live on the earth?**

I also listen that lord Krishna lived for 125 yrs so how is so much difference in lord Ram and lord Krishna. anyway **How many years did lord Krishna live on the earth**

Is there any scripture there about **How many years lord Parshurama and Kalki will live and rule?**

Comment: Ages of Rama and Krishna are already answered. See [At what age was Lord Krishna killed by the hunter?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/937/3500) for Krishna

Comment: As per Valmiki Ramayana, Rama's age = 25 years (age at the time of vanavas) + 14 years (duration of vanavas) + 11000 years (ruled his kingdom)..difference in Rama and Krishna's age is obvious as both the incarnations r from different Yuga...

Comment: This question is already answered in https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17621/lord-shree-rama-ruled-his-kingdom-for-11000-years and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/937/at-what-age-was-lord-krishna-killed-by-the-hunter

Comment: This is a reverse duplicate, as the other Qn doesn't discuss about Kalki and the title describes only for Krishna. Hence voting to reopen.

Comment: @iammilind This question is partially a duplicate of [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6527/36) and partially a duplicate of [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/937/at-what-age-was-lord-krishna-killed-by-the-hunter).  If the duplicative parts are removed then it can be reopened.

Comment: @YDS That figure is enough to refute traditional theory, if Sri Rama ruled for 10000 years, then he must also grow accordingly so he must be a baby at the age of 25 years when he went for Vanavas.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Why it can't be opposite may be in Treta, people used to grow rapidly and then they might have remain young for several years and then when they become old they used to retire to forest.. bdw I hv no issue in accepting a new theory provided u prove all incidents..i hv commented the same in ur other post too..provide the correct translation for 1.1.95,1.1.97,1.20.10,1.38.6,1.41.26,1.42.4,1.42.8,1.42.13,1.43.2,1.51.20,1.57.4,1.62.17,1.62.28,1.63.1,1.63.8,1.63.11,1.63.15,1.63.24,1.64.12,1.64.18,1.64.20,1.65.2,1.65.3,1.65.7,2.2.8,2.2.21,3.50.19,4.58.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Shri RAma: 110+/- years

> दशवर्षसहस्राणि दशवर्षशतानि च । रामो राज्यमुपासित्वा ब्रह्मलोकं प्रयास्यति ।।  [[source]](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/commentaries?language=dv&field_commnetary_tid=8&field_kanda_tid=1&field_sarga_value=1)
> After serving the kingdom for several decades and ten years after [the age of] hundred, RAma proceeded towards *Brahmaloka* (highest of all planes).

Refer [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22715/1049) for more anaylsis.

### Shri Krishna: around 80 years

In Mahabharata's trusted edition, I could find only Drona (85) & Abhimanyu's (16) ages at war time. And based on Gandhari's curse of 36 years, we can infer all the other characters' ages.
If Bhishma was 85-90 years, then Yudhishtira would have been *at least* 40 years younger to him. Which makes him 45+/- years and hence Krishna & Arjuna around 43+/- years. After 36 years, Krishna died during Yadavas' civil war, hence his age would likely be less than 80.

Refer [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16040/1049) for scriptural based analysis.

**Additional verse**: In [Shrimad Bhagavatam 11.6.25](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/6/25), there is a following verse:

> yadu-vaṁśe ’vatīrṇasya bhavataḥ puruṣottama śarac-chataṁ vyatīyāya pañca-viṁśādhikaṁ prabho

Now they have translated as "hundred and twenty five years". However it can also be interpreted as following, if done word by word:

> The best among the men, who descended in Yadu dynasty; O lord you would live hundred autumns, after passing twenty five more [years].

Which means Krishna was at the age of 75 years, when this was said. Had he passed 25 autumns more, he would have finished 100 years. In Sanskrit, a sentence can often be interpreted in more than 1 ways. Also, it matches with the Mahabharata based age of Krishna of <80 years, as mentioned in the linked answer.

### Lord Kalki: Unspecified

Kalki is a futuristic avatAra and there are lots of stories around him. MahabhArata [mentions that](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19603/1049), he will be born during beginning of next Satyuga.  Nothing much about life span.

Comment: Can u please provide correct translation for दशवर्षसहस्राणि दशवर्षशतानि च ।
रामो राज्यमुपासित्वा ब्रह्मलोकं प्रयास्यति ।।1.1.97|| this clearly tells that 10*1000  + 10*100 = 11000 years...if Rama's age is asked then why u r proving Dashratha's age???

Comment: "I am not sure" then what led u to answer this question???

Comment: The translation you have provided would for SB 11.6.25 does not make sense when you would look at the preceding verses. All put together form part of a plea to Sri Krishna to leave earth